# Move directory and delete directory file

Tags: php, directory

I am using PHP to do the move directory function. Now my problem is, I can move the file to another folder, but how original file can be deleted in the original folder? Because I using **rename** function just copy the file to another folder.

`These two folder location`
dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf
dms/500_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf

Below is my coding:

```html
$file_path_2 = "dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf";
$new_file_path = "dms/500_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf";

rename("$file_path_2", "$new_file_path");
```

My result are **dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf and dms/500_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf** both got file.

My expected result are **dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN and dms/500_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf**

Comment: According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) it says *moving it between directories if necessary*, so unless you can't  delete the original file, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move file how you do, then delete folder and file like :

```
$filess = glob('dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/*');
foreach($filess as $filesss){ // iterate files
if(is_file($filesss))
unlink($filesss); // delete file
}
if(is_dir('dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN')) { //check if dir exist
rmdir('dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN'); // delete dir
}
```

If you have only one file:

```
$filess = 'dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN/123.pdf';
unlink($filess); // delete file
if(is_dir('dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN')) { //check if dir exist
rmdir('dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN'); // delete dir
}
```

Comment: Your delete file function is just delete my selected file right? Not all files in the folder right?

Comment: **No**, delete all file in the `dir`, because if you want use `rmdir` the `dir` must be empty

Comment: Ok. Double confirm just 123.pdf in the dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN will be delete. Other file in the dms/400_PENGURUSAN_KEWANGAN no effect right

Comment: So don't use rmdir because have no sense. just use first part of code `$filess` and `unlink`

Comment: I think no need delete the folder just file only